# Rails render site in differnet controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails site and I would like to render the live site through the dashboard. I have created a dashboard for the back end of the website but when a user makes a change I would like them to see it first.

Here's my

**Dashboard.rb**

```
has_many :profiles, :dependent => :destroy

has_many :blogs, :through => :profile, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :videos, :through => :profile, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :albums, :through => :profile, :dependent => :destroy
```

**Dashboard index.html**

```
<%= render :partial => 'profiles/profile', :locals => {:profile => @profile} %>
```

**Profile.rb**

```
belongs_to :dashboard
has_many :blogs, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :videos, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :albums, :dependent => :destroy
```

**_profile.html.erb**

```
<h1><%= @profile.name %></h1>

<% album = @profile.albums.last %>
<% if album.blank? %>
<%= link_to 'Create a new album', new_album_path %></br>
<% else %>
<%= render :partial => 'albums/album', :locals => {:album => @profile.albums.last} %>   
<% end %>

<% blog = @profile.blogs.last %>
<% if blog.blank? %>
<%= link_to 'Create a blog post', new_blog_path %><br/>
<% else %>
<%= render :partial => 'blogs/blog', :locals => {:blog => @profile.blogs.last}%>
<% end %>

<% video = @profile.videos.last %>
<% if video.blank? %>
<%= link_to 'Add new video', new_video_path %></br>
<% else %>
<%= render :partial => 'videos/video', :locals => {:video => @profile.videos.last} %>
<% end %>
```

The above works fine when I'm viewing the site through the frontend but when trying to view it through the dashboard I get the error

> **undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass**

Which is the profile.name line

If I delete the line above I get the

> **undefined method `shows' for nil:NilClass**

Anyone have any suggestions how I can solve this issue?

Comment: Could you post the `index` method of your Dashboard controller?

Comment: I think, You didn't declared the variable (@profile) in your index method. In dashboard controller, def index @profile = SOMETHING.find(?) end

Comment: No i did not define @profile in controller but when I did define     `@profile = Profile.find(params[:id])` in the index I get the the error `Couldn't find Profile without an ID`

Comment: There is a quote missing on the render partial (dashboard). :partial => 'profiles/profile'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be `@profile` find inside controller. If the params id is not valid then it will redirect to root url and if valid it will render page.

```
def index
  @profile = Profile.find_by_id(params[:id])
  @profile || invalid_url!
end

private
def invalid_url!
  flash[:error] = 'URL is not valid !'
  redirect_to root_url
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've defined @profile in the dashboard controller? It seems that @profile is undefined.

Comment: No I did not define it but when I did I received an error. Check the comment above for the error.